# Dashboard has an error on any browser not on the server - New CRM 2011 installation

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics-crm

Just recently we created a Dynamics CRM 2011 instance running and so far it only works from the server that is hosting it. From any client accessing it the dashboard and many items within all show this ("An error has occurred"): [image]

Has anyone encountered this before? What are some steps to take for troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use unsupported browsers. I found that Internet Explorer 11 requires the CRM 2011 page to be loaded in compatibility mode.

I updated latest Rollup and that fixed compatibility for modern browsers like Chrome, Firefox, and IE11.